# What password(s) go in the bacula client's /etc/bacula/bacula-fd.conf?

Tags: client, bacula

I have Bacula 7.0.5 server running on CentOS 7 and I'm trying to configure clients and add them to the server's config using Webmin.
The first question is, can I expect Debian clients using `bacula-client 5.2.6+dfsg-9` to work reliably with `Bacula 7.0.5` server? 
Second question: What passwords do I use in the client's /etc/bacula/bacula-fd.conf?

Comment: 28-Mar 21:35 bacula-dir JobId 10: Fatal error: Unable to authenticate with File daemon at "nfs.nplz.yo:9102". Possible causes:
Passwords or names not the same or
Maximum Concurrent Jobs exceeded on the FD or
FD networking messed up (restart daemon).

Comment: Also, does bconsole need to run as a daemon on clients or does the director run it only during backup jobs?